# Javascript Variable to C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a question about getting Javascript Variables from a local PC JS File to a Local C# Program. 
I'm writing a C# Program for the PC which needs some Variables from a Webpage which is locally located on my PC with just HTML CSS and JS which is displayed in a webview function in my C# Form.

Now I'm reading a Value from the User in my "Webpage" and want to pass this variables to my C# Code so I can use this variables further.

Comment: Rather than duplicate code, here is an answer provided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431948/how-to-pass-generic-list-from-code-behind-to-javascript/26432348#26432348 it utilizes the same premise and should have alot of detail.

Comment: Could you please clarify what type of "C# program" it is - WinForms/WPF, ASP.Net site, something else; what "webview function" means (maybe show code).

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways to get any variable from a browser to your backend. One is to Post a form that contains the variable. The other is to make an AJAX call to send the variable data to some backend service. The AJAX call would, in most cases, be the way to go since no screen refresh is done and involves no interaction or initiation from the user.

Answer (score 0):

use below code :

HTML and Javascript :

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HandleIT() {
        var name = document.getElementById('<%=txtname.ClientID %>').value;
        var address = document.getElementById('<%=txtaddress.ClientID %>').value;
        PageMethods.ProcessIT(name, address, onSucess, onError); 
        function onSucess(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
        function onError(result) {
            alert('Something wrong.');
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Code Behind :**

```
 [WebMethod]
public static string ProcessIT(string name, string address)
{
    string result = "Welcome Mr. " + name + ". Your address is '" + address + "'.";
    return result;
}
```

More information  :
[C# functions returns a value and show in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384416/c-sharp-functions-returns-a-value-and-show-in-webpage)